# Why uses Scapy different methods to distinguish L2 and L3 packets?

Tags: python, scapy

Is there any rationale behind the choice to use distinct methods for sending packets at L2 and L3 in Scapy? Could Scapy not just check if the packet being sent is L2 or higher?

Answer (score 1):

If Scapy were to detect whether the passed packet was L2 or L3, it would mean it has to hardcode a list of layers that are considered “Layer 3” and “Layer 2”.

If you make a custom layer 3, it wouldn’t know in what category it falls, thus it leaves you the choice.

Also that’s historical, dates back from 2008, you can’t break it :-)